# How to Pass A Custom Interface As Props Into A Functional React Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, destructuring, react-functional-component

I've defined an interface `CellState` and I want to pass it as props into a functional component `<Cell state={cellState}` as such:

```
interface CellState {
  location: [number, number];
  clicked: boolean;
  mine: boolean;
  flagged: boolean;
  neighbors: number;
}

const cellState: CellState = {
  location: [0, 0],
  clicked: false,
  mine: true,
  flagged: false,
  neighbors: 0,
} 

function Cell({ location, clicked, mine, flagged, neighbors }: CellState) {
  return(
    <div className={clicked ? 'clicked' : 'unclicked'}>
      CELL
    </div>
  )
}
```

The code above returns an error: `Type '{ state: CellState; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CellState'. Property 'state' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CellState'.  TS2322`

However the code works when I define my function this way:

```
function Cell(props: any, { location, clicked, mine, flagged, neighbors }: CellState) {}
```

What is the correct way to construct the function signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

happens because you dont have `state` prop defined in Cell component.

you can just spread the whole `cellState` object that match the prop requirements of Cell, like below.

```
<Cell {...cellState} />
```